# Insertar codigo html sobre html

Tags: html

Hola creo que esta pregunta es muy basica pero googlee y no consegui informacion por que nose como plantear la pregunta, quiero crear una web el formato obvio es:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mapa Sitio</title>
  <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./createlog.gif" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

pero quiero es sea igual a lo que sale cuando uno le da a los {}  de **stactoverflow**

uqe sale el codigo visible la necesidades que necesito indicar que debe modificar un usuario en mi sitio de internet

ejemplo esta mismo sitio web o el codigo a contimuacion:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mapa Sitio</title>
  <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./createlog.gif" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Megustaria que el codigo comentado aqui se visualise
<html>
<head>
<title>Mapa Sitio</title>
  <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./createlog.gif" />
</head>
<body>
sobre Web
</body>
</html>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar entidades html y remplazar los **`<>`** por **`&lt`** y  **`&gt`** que son entidades que representan a los signos de apertura y cierre.

Puedes ver mas en el siguiente [link:](http://www.noeliaespinosa.com/mostrar-codigo-html-sin-que-se-ejecute/)